# Android Google Maps save marker location to MySQL database

Tags: android, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-markers, android-mapview

I am very new to Android and to programming in general. I am developing an Android application that lets a user place a marker on Google Maps, and once the marker is placed, its location (latitude and longitude) will be uploaded to external MySQL database stored on the server.

I followed these tutorial series to make my Google Maps work properly on Android:

[Google Maps Tutorials](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lywa-2-lQCg)

Now I want to be able to upload latitude and longitude to my database and I'm not sure how to do it.

This is the code that I have right now:

```
public class Main extends MapActivity implements LocationListener{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

//set variables
MapView map; //set map to mapview
long start; //create a starting point when the user presses down on the map
long stop; //create a stop point when the user stops pressing down on the map
MapController controller; //create a map controller that animates where the user is going through the map activity
int x, y; //x and y position on the overlay when the user touches the screen
GeoPoint touchedPoint; //create a geopoint as touchedPoint
Drawable d; //create drawable item
List<Overlay> overlayList; //setup list of overlays
LocationManager lm; //setup location manager
String towers; //setup string called towers
int lat; //create lattitude for the phone's current position
int longi; //create longitude for the phone's current position
private ArrayList<ToDoItem> todoItems;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    map = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mvMain);//set map to mapview in the main.xml
    map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);//zoom function


    Touchy t = new Touchy();//new instance of touchy class
    overlayList = map.getOverlays();//list of overlays
    overlayList.add(t);//add touchy instance (t) to a list of overlays
    controller = map.getController();//setup controller
    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(51643234, 7848593);//setup geopoint
    controller.animateTo(point);//animate controller to that location
    controller.setZoom(6);//set zoom level

    //create drawable item and its location
    d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.yellow);

    //Placing marker at location
    //retrieve location manager for controlling the location updates 
    lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria crit = new Criteria();//setup criteria


    towers = lm.getBestProvider(crit, false);//return the provider that best fits the given criteria
    Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(towers);//access location through location manager and get the last known location called towers

    if (location != null){
        lat = (int) (location.getLatitude() *1E6);//get latitude
        longi = (int) (location.getLongitude() *1E6);//get longitude
        //add overlay to the list
        GeoPoint ourLocation = new GeoPoint(lat, longi);//setup geopoint as ourLocation with lat and long
        OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(ourLocation, "Hello", "2nd String");//pass in outLocation to OverlayItem
        CustomMarker custom = new CustomMarker(d, Main.this);
        custom.insertPinpoint(overlayItem);
        overlayList.add(custom);
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Couldn't find provider", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

@Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    //when pause is pressed remove location updates
    lm.removeUpdates(this);
}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    //when the resume is pressed request location updates
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(towers, 500, 1, this);
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}


//overlay class that handles all touch events
class Touchy extends Overlay{
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e, MapView m){ //onTouchEvent method which includes a motion even and a map view
    if(e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){ //when the user presses down on the overlay
        start = e.getEventTime();//start point when the event happens 
        x = (int) e.getX();//x and y coordinates based on where the user touched the overlay
        y = (int) e.getY();
        touchedPoint = map.getProjection().fromPixels(x, y);//sets a geopoint based on where the user has touched on the screen. Relates the map activity to the user's actual touch on the overlay

    }
    if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){ //when the user stops pressing down on the overlay
        stop = e.getEventTime();//stop point when the event happens
    }
    if (stop - start > 1500){ //if the user presses on the overlay for more than 1.5 seconds
        AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main.this).create();//setup alert dialog for the Main class
        alert.setTitle("Pick an Option");//set the title for the alert
        alert.setMessage("Please pick an option");//set the message for the alert


        //BUTTON 1
        //set a button for the alert. Refer to a dialogue interface for this OnClickListener
        alert.setButton("Place a Marker", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            //when the button is clicked
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(touchedPoint, "Hello", "2nd String");//setup overlay item and refer to touchedPoint which is geopoint
                CustomMarker custom = new CustomMarker(d, Main.this);//setup a custom marker with a "d" in the Main class
                custom.insertPinpoint(overlayItem);//add an overlayItem to the pinpoint array list
                overlayList.add(custom);//add custom overlay to the overlay list
                map.invalidate();//make MapView draw itself
                SaveRemote();
            }
        });
```

This is not all the code that I have in my program, but I tried to include everything that is relevant to my problem and might help you solve it.

If you scroll down to "Button 1" you can see the code that I've written that places a marker on the location where the user has pressed. At the very end of Button 1 code I call a method SaveRemote that is responsible for saving the actual latitude and longitude based on where the marker is placed.

I don't know what to put in this method and how to connect it to my main program and get the actual latitude and longitude from where the user has pressed.

This is the code for the method that I've written

```
public void SaveRemote(){

      String result = "";

         InputStream is = null;
         try{
             HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
             HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("myservername.com/insert.php");

             ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();


              }catch(Exception e){
                 Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
            }
          }
```

As you can see I call the insert.php file on my server that runs an insert query which adds marker's latitude and longitude to the database.

And this is the actual insert.php code:

```
 $con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("mydatabase", $con);

$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO markers (lat, lng) VALUES (lat, lng)";

mysql_close($con);
```

I would really appreciate your help as I don't know how to send the marker's location to the SaveRemote method which in turn will send this data to the php file.

Thank you

Comment: this is quite an old post - did you already 'help yourself' or are you still stuck there? Basically the way to go would be to extract the coordinates from your GeoPoint and then to submit them using REST / Json.

Answer (score 0):

Hey i might be kinda late but you can resolve this using setOnMarkerDragListener something like this:

```
          map.setOnMarkerDragListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener() {
                @Override
                public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {
                    //Toast.makeText(TerminosYC.this.getActivity(), "Arrastra el marcador, hasta el lugar deseado",
                    //        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    LatLng position = marker.getPosition();
                    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                            new LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude), 15));
                }

                @Override
                public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {
                      //       System.out.println("Arrastrando...");
                    LatLng position = marker.getPosition();
                    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                            new LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude), 15));
                }

                @Override
                public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
                    LatLng position = marker.getPosition();
                    latitudeeeee = position.latitude;
                    longitudeeee = position.longitude;
                    //Toast.makeText(
                    //        TerminosYC.this.getActivity(),
                    //        "Lat " + position.latitude + " "
                    //                + "Long " + position.longitude,
                    //        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    //map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                    //        new LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude), 15));

                }
            });

        }
    });
```

Comment: You have my appreciation because you answered to this question even after 5 years.

Comment: You're welcome and you really deserve this for your effort. That's pretty cool.